# Can I get a refund due to bundle sales on Steam?

Tags: steam

So, I bought one game on Steam, and a few days later looked at another game I wanted. I scrolled down, and saw that it had a bundle with both games in it for nearly the same price that I payed for the first game.

I had already put 25 hours into the first game, so there was no chance of refund. It's probably too late now, so I'm going to buy the second game before the Steam sale ends, tomorrow.

For future reference, would it be possible for me to get both games bundle price, seeing as I bought both in the same sale as the bundle?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, within reason.

You need to have purchased the game within 14 days, and have played it for no more than 2 hours.

Failing that, you do get an additional discount on bundles where you already own some of the games.

---

## Refunding Games with Steam

Steam have a refund policy for games. They go as far as confirming that this policy allows you to repurchase games that go on special.

> ### How to Request a Refund
>
> Valve will, upon request via [help.steampowered.com](https://help.steampowered.com/), issue a refund for any title that is requested within 14 days of purchase and has been played for less than 2 hours. Even if you fall outside of the refund rules we've described, you can submit a request and we'll take a look at it.
>
> Additional information and troubleshooting instructions for existing refund requests can be found in our [Common Refund Questions](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4873-QOSK-5126) FAQ. 
> **[- "How To Request A Refund" @ Steam Support](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6695-QIKM-7966)**

> ### What can I request a refund for?
>
> Valve will, upon request via [help.steampowered.com](https://help.steampowered.com/), issue a refund for any title that is requested within 14 days of purchase and has been played for less than 2 hours - this includes online, offline and shared library playtime. Even if you fall outside of the refund rules we've described, you can submit a request and we'll take a look at it.
>
> ### I bought a game right before it went on sale. Can I get a refund and repurchase it at the sale price?
>
> Yes.
>
> If you have not already requested a refund, [make sure the purchase is eligible](http://store.steampowered.com/steam_refunds/) and submit a request [here](http://help.steampowered.com/). 
> Please note that approved refunds may take up to 7 days to process. 
> **[- "Common Refund Questions" @ Steam Support](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4873-QOSK-5126)**

## Other Options

### Always Double Check the Bundles

When you look at a games store page, you can see the bundles that game is a part of. It is always worth checking the additional bundles. You might find it a better option to directly buy the bundle. You might even consider holding off and purchasing the bundle at a later date, depending on the situation.

### Bundles Still Give You Discounts

As *Mixxiphoid* mentioned, you still get discounts on a bundle, even when you own some of the games. Steam applies a further discount to account for the games you already own. To give a real world example, I own the "Orange Box" collection and "Left 4 Dead 2". These games are a part of the "Valve Complete Pack BUNDLE". At the time of writing this answer, the bundle is selling for <del>A$213.00</del> A$19.08; but when they take into account the games I already own, the price goes down to <del>A$146.50</del> A$13.12.

> Bundles are a special discount on a set of products. If you already own some of the products contained in the bundle, purchasing the bundle will allow you to "complete the set", paying only for the products you don't already own while still receiving the full bundle discount on each of those products.
>
> **- BUNDLE rollover notification found via the Steam application**

[image: image evidence of bundle discount due to owning some of the games]

Comment: Note that "because it went on sale" is explicitly allowed and *not* considered abuse of the system (though you need to meet the 2 hour/2 week limits).

Comment: @Studoku, I directly quote their FAQ where they stqte this.

Comment: It seems my comment was removed from the question, the reference is confusing now. Perhaps remove it?

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer!  I have 2 questions, though.  If you own all the games in a bundle, what would steam do if you purchased the bundle, and if you received one of the games in the bundle as a gift, would steam still discount it?

Comment: @Millard you can't buy the bundle, not for yourself or a friend, if you have all the items in the bundle. There is also no difference between a purchase or a gift, you get the same discount of the bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Mixxiphoid , and thank you Gnemlock.  I thought I selected your answer a while ago, but here it is now anyway.

Comment: I'd like to add to this by saying that while "bought in the last 14 days and no more than 2 hours played" is the official rule, I've found them to be flexible on this in the past. I've had games refunded after four hours of play after I discovered major technical problems that weren't apparent in the first two hours. If you fill out a refund request and explain the situation then they might help you even if you've exceeded the allotted time, although the 25 hours that the OP mentions exceeds it by *a lot*.

Comment: Yep, refunds actually go through someone. The period limits are essentially limits for _unconditional_ refund. Anecdotally, I've obtained a refund of a game I had played for over 10 hours in its singleplayer mode, because only later it was observed that the multiplayer did not work and the developers had no plan to fix it. Since the game was still listed on the store as having multiplayer as a feature, I managed to get a refund even though it was a bit over a month later.